# android UsbDeviceConnection.requestWait() with timeout

Tags: android, usb, android-usb

I am trying to interface a USB tuner card to the android device (version 19).

Currently I am using UsbDeviceConnection.requestWait() to read the data followed by UsbRequest.queue of 16kb.  Things all work fine.

In case of no input for the tuner USB wont receive any data.  In this case the requestWait() is blocking forever.  I tried to use the UsbRequest.close and UsbRequest.cancel but was not useful.

I looked into the link "http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39522", it mentions same problem, but required to write a new JNI interface.

My requirement is that I should be able to come out of the wait and would like not to attempt to write new JNI inteface (as per the above post).  Please suggest.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?